# MailMerge using sql server database

Tags: c#, sql-server-2008, mailmerge

I'm trying to do MailMerge with SQL server database as the datasource in c#. Is it possible? I've googled for days without any valid results. Can someone provide me with any valid links or explain how to acheive this? Pls Help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: yes. I have to merge the data returned from the SQL server stored procedure to MS word

Comment: what i've already tried was the microsoft link
http://support.microsoft.com/?kbid=301659. When I try to give the connection string in CreateDataSource method it throws the command failed error

Comment: Object oName = "C:\\DataDoc.doc";
            Object oHeader = "FirstName, LastName, Address, CityStateZip";
            Object oTrue = true;
            Object oSqlStatment = "Select * from Table_Name";
            Object oConnectIon = "Data source=IP\\SQL2008;Database=Test;User id=Test;Password=TestP;Min Pool Size=20;Max Pool Size=200";
            wrdDoc.MailMerge.CreateDataSource(ref oName, ref oMissing,
                ref oMissing, ref oHeader, ref oTrue, ref oSqlStatment,
                ref oMissing, ref oConnectIon, ref oTrue); 
This is what i've done

Answer (score 0):

1. It's possible to connect to a Table or View, but you need to use OpenDataSource (not CreateDataSource), providing a suitable .odc path/filename (which you create manually in Word) as the Name parameter, and a suitable SQL Query in SQLStatement. That gives you an OLE DB connection. You can connect vie ODBC, but something in the communications chain does not do Unicode stuff properly which means that NVARCHAR and other "N" types are not returned. You can use an empty .odc as long as you provide all the connection info. you need in the call, e.g. (in VBA)

ActiveDocument.MailMerge.OpenDataSource _

```
Name:="c:\myodcs\empty.odc", _
Connection:="Provider=SQLOLEDB.1;Integrated Security=SSPI;" & _
"Persist Security Info=False;Initial Catalog=mydb;Data Source=myserver;" _
SQLSatatement:="SELECT * FROM [mytable]", _
SubType:=wdMergeSubTypeOther
```

where "myserver" is the name of the server running your SQl Server database,
"mydb" is the name of the database you want to access and "mytable" is the
table or view from which you want to retrieve data.

That uses the old SQL Server client. You'll need at least to change the Provider name to use the new one.

You may or may not have to qualify table names with database/catalog names, and you may have to take account of the following article:

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/918295

1. Connecting to a typical SP is another matter. There is an error in the object that Word uses to do it that AFAIK has not been fixed and has no good workaround. For some details and the only suggestions I know of, see

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/worddev/thread/272cf1a8-ea98-49a9-b05f-82cfec497a6a

Comment: Thank u bibadiak for ur valuable reply. Like u've mentioned I got the error "Record 1 Contained too few datafields". I followed the steps mentioned in the article u gave me and also I've used full database schema in the SQLStatement. But now I get the error "Office could not open your file because of security / password issues. Please check to see that your password is correct". I've given the correct password.

Comment: 1. After around SQL Server 2000, I don't think I ever got any connection that did not use Integrated Security to work. I never found out where the problem was, sorry.

2. What is your connection string?

3. If you have Excel, it is worth trying to connect from Excel (which is typically rather better at it). If you can, we have to assume a problem with Word.

Comment: The problem is I'm not getting any fields in the datasource. The only thing I get is M_ and M_1.

Comment: Are you able to make any kind of connection at all to this database using either Word or Excel? I have looked again connecting without Integrated Security and the setup I have here does seem to work. The connection string is more like this: "Provider=SQLOLEDB.1;" & _
"Persist Security Info=True;User ID=myloginname;Password=mypassword;Initial Catalog=mydb;Data Source=myserver;"...Unfortunately, it is necessary to embed the password in the VBA. If you are unable to make any connection from Word or Excel, one possibility is that the server will only accept connections from the newer provider...

Comment: Hi bibadiak, Im pefectly able to connect to the specific database using  excel.

Comment: @"Data source=ServerName;Database=TestDB;User id=ID;Password=pswd;Min Pool Size=20;Max Pool Size=200;" 
This is my connection string

Comment: The newer provider may be called SQLNCLI.1, SQLNCLI10.1, and there may be a more recent one. As far as I know, the connection string parameters in this case would be the same, but you might need to check with people with more expertise in SQL Server.

Comment: Just read your Excel connection comments. What does the complete connection string you are using in Word look like? And what SQL are you using?

Answer (score 0):

I know this is old, but I've struggled trying to figure out a solution for Word 2013 and newer.  I came up with this for using parameters to filter data.  It's easier to use an .odc connection (Office Data Connection) in Microsoft Word than the older method of passing parameters.

Step 1:  Create a Word form to use later.  In Microsoft Word 2013 or later click on the Mailings ribbon tab, then drop down Select Recipients and select use existing connection and either select an existing odc file or click New Source.  If you're setting up a new source follow the wizard.  Create the letter, form, label... using Insert Merge Field to add the data fields to the document.  Save the document when finished. If possible use integrated security. Note, they are generally stored in C:\Users\\Documents\My Data Sources.

In my case I have a view (vAppointment) with the fields AppointmentID, FirstName, and LastName.  In the document I added the fields to the word document to verify it works.  If I generate mail merge it fills in all of the data.

Step 2: In a C# project hook up the following function and change the paths for the word document and odc file.  You'll also need to update the QueryString to reflect your data:

```
    public void RunMailMerge()
    {
        try
        {
            object isTrue = true;
            object notTrue = false;

            Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Document wordDoc = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Document();
            Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application wordApp = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application();
            string filename = @"C:\<path>\<the file you created>.docx";
            wordDoc = wordApp.Documents.Add(Template: filename);
            wordApp.Visible = true;

            object format = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.WdOpenFormat.wdOpenFormatAuto;

            wordDoc.MailMerge.OpenDataSource(@"C:\Users\<username>\Documents\My Data Sources\<your connection file>.odc",
                      ref format,
                      ref notTrue,    // ConfirmConversion
                      ref isTrue      // Set as ReadOnly so the user can't overwrite the document
                      );
            // Check the QueryString to see what is already there, add your parameters as needed.  In my case I added "WHERE AppointmentID = 4"
            wordDoc.MailMerge.DataSource.QueryString = "SELECT * FROM \"vAppointment\" WHERE AppointmentID = 4";
            wordDoc.MailMerge.Execute(ref notTrue);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            string t = ex.Message;
            string s = ex.StackTrace;
            string msg = t + Environment.NewLine + s;
        }
    }
```